# Owner draw CSliderCtrl using MFC: why my program-created slider has an incorrect channel rect?

Tags: windows, mfc

I am trying to implement an owner draw CSliderCtrl. It seems drawing is fine, however the mouse to change the thumb position is very weird. It is limited only in a very small rect. And I found that the rect by GetChannelRect is much smaller than the rect I used to create the slider control.
Below is .h file:

```
#if !defined(AFX_OWNDRAWSLIDER_H__82981708_4CBC_4D1E_8982_504E99BE489D__INCLUDED_)
#define AFX_OWNDRAWSLIDER_H__82981708_4CBC_4D1E_8982_504E99BE489D__INCLUDED_

#if _MSC_VER > 1000
#pragma once
#endif // _MSC_VER > 1000
// OwnDrawSlider.h : header file
//

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// COwnDrawSlider window

class COwnDrawSlider : public CSliderCtrl
{
// Construction
public:
    COwnDrawSlider();

// Attributes
public:
    CBrush black_brush;

// Operations
public:

// Overrides
    // ClassWizard generated virtual function overrides
    //{{AFX_VIRTUAL(COwnDrawSlider)
    //}}AFX_VIRTUAL

// Implementation
public:
    virtual ~COwnDrawSlider();

    // Generated message map functions
protected:
    //{{AFX_MSG(COwnDrawSlider)
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg HBRUSH OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor);
    afx_msg BOOL OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC);
    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    //}}AFX_MSG

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//{{AFX_INSERT_LOCATION}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ will insert additional declarations immediately before the previous line.

#endif // !defined(AFX_OWNDRAWSLIDER_H__82981708_4CBC_4D1E_8982_504E99BE489D__INCLUDED_)
```

Here is the OwnDrawSlider class cpp:

```
    // OwnDrawSlider.cpp : implementation file
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "OwnDrawSlider.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__;
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// COwnDrawSlider

COwnDrawSlider::COwnDrawSlider()
{
    black_brush.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
}

COwnDrawSlider::~COwnDrawSlider()
{
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(COwnDrawSlider, CSliderCtrl)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(COwnDrawSlider)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
    ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// COwnDrawSlider message handlers

void COwnDrawSlider::OnPaint() 
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    // TODO: Add your message handler code here
    CRect channelRect,thumbRect;
    GetChannelRect(&channelRect);
    GetThumbRect(&thumbRect);

    GetClientRect(&channelRect);
    thumbRect=channelRect;
    channelRect.top+=5;
    channelRect.bottom-=5;
    int mid=(channelRect.top+channelRect.bottom)/2;
    int w=channelRect.right-channelRect.left;
    int pos=GetPos();
    int minVal,maxVal;
    GetRange(minVal,maxVal);
    thumbRect.left=(pos-minVal)*w/(maxVal-minVal);
    thumbRect.right=thumbRect.left+(channelRect.right-channelRect.left)*0.025f;
    thumbRect.top+=12;
    thumbRect.bottom-=12;
    //draw the channel
    //CBrush whiteBrush(RGB(255,255,255));
    //dc.SelectObject(whiteBrush);
    //dc.FrameRect(&channelRect,&whiteBrush);
    //draw the thumb
    CBrush yellowBrush(RGB(255,255,0));
    dc.SelectObject(yellowBrush);
    dc.Ellipse(&thumbRect);

    CFont myFont;
    myFont.CreatePointFont(96,"Tahoma");
    dc.SetBkColor(RGB(0,0,0));
    dc.SetTextColor(RGB(255,255,255));

    dc.SelectObject(&myFont);
    char msg[128];
    sprintf(msg,"%d",pos);
    CRect msgRect=thumbRect;
    msgRect.top=thumbRect.bottom;
    msgRect.bottom=msgRect.top+16;
    int mid0=(thumbRect.left+thumbRect.right)/2;
    msgRect.left=mid0-6*strlen(msg);
    msgRect.right=mid0+6*strlen(msg);
    dc.DrawText(msg,strlen(msg),&msgRect,DT_CENTER);

    sprintf(msg,"%d",minVal);
    msgRect.left=channelRect.left;
    msgRect.right=channelRect.left+12*strlen(msg);
    dc.DrawText(msg,strlen(msg),&msgRect,DT_LEFT);

    sprintf(msg,"%d",maxVal);
    msgRect.left=channelRect.right-12*strlen(msg);
    msgRect.right=channelRect.right;
    dc.DrawText(msg,strlen(msg),&msgRect,DT_RIGHT);

    //draw the axis
    CPen yellowPen(PS_SOLID,3,RGB(255,255,255));
    dc.SelectObject(yellowPen);
    dc.MoveTo(channelRect.left,mid);
    dc.LineTo(channelRect.right,mid);
    dc.MoveTo(channelRect.left,channelRect.top+12);
    dc.LineTo(channelRect.left,channelRect.bottom-12);
    dc.MoveTo(channelRect.right,channelRect.top+12);
    dc.LineTo(channelRect.right,channelRect.bottom-12);

    CPen thinPen(PS_SOLID,1,RGB(255,255,0));
    dc.SelectObject(thinPen);
    int numTick=GetNumTics();
    DWORD* ptick=GetTicArray();
    float pixelPerTick=w*1.0/numTick;
    for(int i=0;i<numTick;i++)
    {
        dc.MoveTo((ptick[i])*pixelPerTick+channelRect.left,mid-3);
        dc.LineTo((ptick[i])*pixelPerTick+channelRect.left,mid+3);
    }

    // Do not call CSliderCtrl::OnPaint() for painting messages
}

HBRUSH COwnDrawSlider::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor) 
{
    HBRUSH hbr = CSliderCtrl::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);

    // TODO: Change any attributes of the DC here

    // TODO: Return a different brush if the default is not desired
    return black_brush;
}

BOOL COwnDrawSlider::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC) 
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    RECT client;
    GetClientRect(&client);
    //COLORREF color=pDC->GetBkColor();
    COLORREF color=::GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOW);
    //FillRect(pDC->m_hDC,&client,::GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));
    //pDC->FillSolidRect(&client,color);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(&client,RGB(0,0,0));
    return true;//do not call OnEraseBkgrnd, it will fill it white
    //return CSliderCtrl::OnEraseBkgnd(pDC);
}
```

Create the slider using program (no resource associated with it):

```
pFrameSlider=new COwnDrawSlider();
pFrameSlider->Create(WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_OWNERDRAW|TBS_HORZ|TBS_AUTOTICKS,rButton,this,ID_FRAME_SLIDER);
//pFrameSlider->SizeToContent();
pFrameSlider->SetTicFreq(50);
pFrameSlider->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

In the parent window, the NM_RELEASECAPTURE is trapped. When created, the rect=[9,57,384,822]. The rect obtained by the GetChannelRect is [19,23, 8, 40]. and the mouse operation is limited in this rect.
My question is: why the two rect are so different? How can I change the channel rect by program (without any resource associated with it)?

Comment: Have you tried `CSliderCtrl::SetThumbLength()`?

Comment: No. I am using vc6.0. The msdn shows no this function.

Comment: You can still send the related message directly to the slider:  
`#define TBM_SETTHUMBLENGTH      (WM_USER+27)`  
`::SendMessage(hwndSlider, TBM_SETTHUMBLENGTH, (WPARAM)nLength, 0L);`

Comment: ps. If you download the latest Windows SDK this  will give you all the latest control messages

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to set the ThumbLength, but it seems there is no effect. SetThumbLength should set the length of the thumb, right? It seems that is not what my problem is. My problem is that the mouse only works in the very small ChannelRect.

Comment: Remove the `BS_OWNERDRAW` in `Create` call. This flag is only valid for CButton creation. By setting this flag in the CSliderCtrl Create call, you actually create a slider in vertical orientation.

Comment: Thanks. I came the same conclusion that OWNERDRAW is not workable for CSliderCtrl. Sorry I did not get back to check this. Thank you for your great comments